# How to rank pandas df based on priorities and conditions?

Tags: pandas, sorting, if-statement, ranking, rank

`df.head()`

```
     Win  Lose  Draw
A1   3.0   5.0   6.0
A2   3.0   4.0   3.0
A3   0.0   6.0   8.0
A4   0.0   10.0  4.0
A5   8.0   2.0   4.0
```

I want to rank dataframe `df.rank(method='dense').astype(int)` based on following conditions:

1. Wins --> More the wins, higher the rank`
2. Lose --> If ranks are equal, then Row with less number of loses/more number of draws will be higher in rank `Output :`df_rank`

   ```
       Rank
   A1    3  # Has wins equal to A2, but has more losses, so ranked after A2
   A2    2  
   A3    4
   A4    5  # Has most number of losses. So ranked last
   A5    1  #Has most number of wins
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idea is rank each column separately, with `ascending=False` for `Win`, create `Series` of tuples and `rank` again:

```
a = df.Win.rank(method='dense', ascending=False)
b = df.Lose.rank(method='dense')

df['Rank'] = pd.Series(zip(a, b), index=df.index).rank(method='dense').astype(int)
print (df)
    Win  Lose  Draw  Rank
A1  3.0   5.0   6.0     3
A2  3.0   4.0   3.0     2
A3  0.0   6.0   8.0     4
A4  0.0  10.0   4.0     5
A5  8.0   2.0   4.0     1
```